# Rails Model Generator tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, code-generation

Newbie to Rails here, I was wondering if there is a tool which can be used to represent relationships using drag drop like MySQL WorkBench(image below) and can generate model automatically for us along with relations.

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [packtpub.com](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/workbench-article-image1.png))</sub>

I think it would be a great tool to have but its surprising to find none available from quick search, is there some huge disadvantage for creating models this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tersely answer your question, no, I don't know of any that directly interface with rails. But if you just want to see the relationships between models, you could play around with gems like [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and [RailRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/).

While I'm sure you could use something like MySQL Workbench to mess with tables used by a Rails app, the Migration features of rails are very quick, effective and **integrated with your app**.

Syntax for generating models and updating table attributes is available in the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

For example, if you want to create a user table, it's just a few keystrokes away:

```
rails generate model User user_name:string password:string favorite_food:string lucky_number:integer vegan:boolean
```

If you ever decide you want to add/remove/change a column, you can do something like:

```
 rails g migration AddStudentIdtoUsers student_id:integer
 rails g migration RemoveVeganfromUsers vegan:boolean
```

You can even go edit these proposed changes before you implement them if you want. Then you would run `rake db:migrate` to actually implement the changes you've laid out.

Moral of the story, give the CLI a chance. **Spend less time messing with SQL and more time building your app.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this question is fairly old, but I have recently started building a fairly complex schema (around 200 models) that I wanted to be able to visualise.

I have so far created the schema in MySQL workbench, and have come upon a gem that allows the workbench generated .mwb files to be used to create ActiveRecord models: https://github.com/woolf/active_workbench. Perhaps this will be of use to you, as you are already using MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

One of the premises of Rails is that you can use only the command line and a good text-editor and be fully productive with the framework.

Thus using the command-line generators is really quick as is using migrations. Once you master the syntax, creating the model in that way is just a lot faster then using some GUI.

Answer (score -1):

RubyMine [has this feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/demos/rubymine_model_diagram.html). Give it a [try](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/).